# Two formulations of Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $ X $ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, and $ C_c(X) $ be the space of all complex-valued continuous functions with compact support on $ X $.

As far as I know, there are two formulations of Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem.

**Formulation 1 (e.g., D. L. Cohn, *Measure Theory*, 2nd edition, Theorem 7.2.8).** Positive linear functionals on $ C_c(X) $ correspond bijectively to positive Borel measures $ \mu $ on $ X $ that is

- outer regular for all Borel subsets $ A \subseteq X $, which means
  $$ \mu(A) = \inf \{\mu(U) \mid \text{open subsets $ U \subseteq X $ containing $ A $}\}, $$
- inner regular for open subsets $ U \subseteq X $, which means
  $$ \mu(U) = \sup \{\mu(K) \mid \text{compact subsets $ K \subseteq U $}\}, $$
- finite on compact subsets.

**Formulation 2 (e.g., N. Bourbaki, *Integration*, Chapter IX, Section 3, No. 2, Theorem 2).** Positive linear functionals on $ C_c(X) $ correspond bijectively to positive Borel measures $ \mu $ on $ X $ that is

- inner regular for all Borel subsets $ A \subseteq X $, which means
  $$ \mu(A) = \sup \{\mu(K) \mid \text{compact subsets $ K \subseteq A $}\}, $$
- finite on compact subsets.

So, there should be a natural correspondence between the classes of positive Borel measures in Formulation 1 and 2.

**Question.** Is it possible to describe and prove this correpondence directly (i.e., without using positive linear functionals)?

Comment: From Bourbaki's *Integration*, chap. V, § 1, no. 1 and chap. IV, § 1, nos. 1 to 4, it seems likely that to go from formulation 1 to formulation 2, you let
$$\mu^\bullet(A)=\sup\{\mu(A\cap K)~|~K\text{ compact subset of }X\}$$
and $\mu^\bullet$ will be a measure as in formulation 2, and to go from formulation 2 to formulation 1, you let
$$\mu^*(A)=\inf\{\mu(U)~|~U\text{ open subset of }X\text{ containing }A\}$$
and $\mu^*$ will be a measure as in formulation 1... but writing everything down properly is probbaly very long.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the argument, precisely the one as @P.P.Tuong suggested, has been written down in “Radon measures on arbitrary topological spaces and cylindrical measures” by Laurent Schwartz, chapter I.